# SQL Server 2005 is changing decimal to integer

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-2005, windows-7, visual-studio-2005

My column's datatype is `decimal(18,0)` but when I am entering value in to database `2.3` it changes into `2`.

Comment: Edit the question in a way it will become a **question**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For storing this value  field should have a type of `decimal(18,1)`

Check it:

```
SELECT CAST(2.3 as decimal(18,0))
SELECT CAST(2.3 as decimal(18,1))
```

Comment: thanks for help i was thinking there is problem with my sql server installation thanks really for help.

Answer (score 3):

`decimal(18, 0)` means that you want to create a decimal field which stores:

- 18 digits, shared between the left and right sides of the decimal place.
- 0 digits to the **right** of the decimal place.

That explains why `2.3` is being turned into `2`. For further detail, see the [msdn documentation for the decimal datatype](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx).